# Which 32-bit features are still vulnerable to "Retbleed" in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, 32bit, vulnerability

I'm updating my kernel to protect my system against the "Retbleed" exploit, and I know that [affected 32-bit things haven't received the necessary mitigations](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-x86-Retbleed). I'm wondering which 32-bit features I need to disable in the Linux kernel to be fully protected.

I've found `CONFIG_X86_X32_ABI` and `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION` so far. I'd like to maintain the ability to execute 32-bit binaries with reduced performance, if possible. **Which (or both) of these config options enable the exploit? Are there any other features I need to disable?**

I'm aware that [some older CPUs must disable SMT to be fully protected](https://lwn.net/Articles/900917/), but my CPU is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a 32-bit kernel.

If you're able to turn on `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`, then you're not running a 32-bit kernel.

You're running a 64-bit kernel.  This is the correct type of kernel for you to run.  No configuration change is required.

https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/Ys%2FkfDk7mVE09N3L@worktop.programming.kicks-ass.net/

> > > We are booting the i386 kernel on an x86 machine.
> > > With Spectre V2 patches merged into Linux mainline we have been noticing
> > > RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to
> > > RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!
> >
> > That's funny.  I don't think that's a valid combination that should be
> > cared about, but I'll leave it to Pawan to comment if it is something
> > that is "real" to be concerned for.
>
> Yeah, so far nobody cared to fix 32bit. If someone *realllllly* cares
> and wants to put the effort in I suppose I'll review the patches, but
> seriously, you shouldn't be running 32bit kernels on Skylake / Zen
> based systems, that's just silly.